# Devise Gem Redirect After Two Different Registration Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

So currently my web app has two ways for a user to register. One is from clicking a button on the homepage called 'Post a Project' that will take user to multi-step Post a Project wizard. The other is a link called 'Register' which will take user to logged in area Dashboard.

I am currently using the latest Devise gem. The Post Project wizard's 1st step is a very similar Register form as the other way to register. Both of which initially create a new user account via Devise.

So basically, I am needing a way that once a user Signs Up and creates an account, they are redirected accordingly to whichever Register route they took. So far; I have this in my code which is unsuccessful as it takes both Register forms to the Dashboard.

application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if session[:registered_from] == projects_register_path
    new_project_path
  else
    account_index_path
  end
end
```

I am not sure what else to include, so please ask away and I'll more info needed up...

Thanks,
James F.

Comment: How about setting a commit value on submit button in forms? And in the controller you can redirect based the commit value.

Comment: not a bad idea! will research into how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for anybody with the same problem. Ended up needing to define my 'session[:registered_from] = projects_register_path' in my projects_controller under the before_filter method I had set.